# Moving external library to my internal library so that i could edit the library?

Tags: android

I would like to ask about how to move the external library to internal lib folder in my application.

this library I get from android arsenal. [Android Arsenal - Photo Picker](https://github.com/donglua/PhotoPicker)

Every time I change its Javas or layout xmls file and compile it, this pop message show up

[image: Pop out Message in Android studio 1.5]

[image]

Comment: You need to download the source code of the library from github to edit it.

Comment: thanks neeraj. Ill try ur suggestion